# detect soundwave image in camera stream

Tags: python, image-processing, real-time, object-detection

I am working on my personal project and I want to detect the image of the soundwave from camera input (in real-time). What I need is to detect soundwave like normal face detection or QR scanner code but instead of QR of face, there will be a soundwave image.

I am familiar with OpenCV, but I don't know how and where to begin. Any help would be appreciated.

I need it in my personal android app, but for sake of simplicity, I want to implement it first in python.

A sample of soundwave image is something like this:
[image: Soundwave Image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

Consider your image's size is (w=1000)*(h=500). Make an empty 1000*1 array. Go through each single column and in every column, find the top filled pixel (the non-zero pixel with the minimum row value (which this row value, show us the magnitude of the wave!) and save this value in the corresponding pixel of the 1000*1 array. 
By this way you will have a 1000-bit signal which you can do similarity measuring on that, with other signals (other waves). There are lots of criteria for similarity checking. One way is to calculate the area between the two signal.